# Que signifie "avoir du crime" ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Bonjour,

Dans *Le Pont de Londres* :

> c'est comme ça que tu nous bahutes!... Dis que t'**as pas du crime**! Ah!
> mézigue tu cherres!...

Savez-vous ce que signifie *avoir du crime* ici ?

Answer (score 2):

L'expression n'est plus utilisée. On dirait aujourd'hui: avoir du [toupet](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toupet) ou du [culot](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/culot/1).

Ref: [Bob](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/67747)

Comment: Sympa la Ref: ! — Il y en a qui ont changé complètement de sens après la seconde guerre mondiale.